# Scroll content not working in iOS ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

I have extremely slow scrolling on my ionic app using an iOS device but other devices are working fine.
Is there any another easier way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, it is always a good practice to explain problems in detail and include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem or portion of code that you think causing problem/error. You can also follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you please provide the code?

Answer (score 0):

Please apply below line at app.scss, it may be helpful for u :

/*fix scroll lock on ios12.2*/ 
ion-app.platform-ios12 ion-content { pointer-events: auto;}